# promiscuous mode not working

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireshark, sniffing

I've searched, and heard that the promiscuous mode lets us listen to all wireless trafic in the Access Point that we are associated with. But when i use this mode with wireshark, i don't get the exact results that I was expecting, I only get the traffic of my machine, and the broadcast packets.

When i saw that, i thought that may be there is no traffic in my Access Point, so I did some arp spoofing with my other machine (to become the man in the middle between one of my machines and the AP), in this case, wireshark show me that machine trafic.

So, what's wrong ?? may be my wireless card doesn't support promiscuous mode ?? or may be my Access Point uses some technologie that prevents the sniffing ?? In both cases, please give me an explanation and may be a solution if there is one.

PS : I use Ubuntu 15.10 with linux kernel > 4.

PS2 : This is all legal, I have a project on sniffing, and all the tests that i am doing, i'm doing them on my material.

Comment: Start from the ground up. Are you capturing on the right interface? Be certain what data you're actually looking at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Promiscious mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) will not always allow you to see traffic while Client isolation is in play. Promiscuous mode just means that your PC will process all frames received and decoded. On many APs/wnics/oses Promiscuous mode will not see traffic for other systems.

From the Wireshark documentation:

> Monitor mode
>
> In monitor mode the SSID filter mentioned above is disabled and all
>   packets of all SSID's from the currently selected channel are
>   captured.
>
> Even in promiscuous mode, an 802.11 adapter will only supply to the
>   host packets of the SSID the adapter has joined, assuming promiscuous
>   mode works at all; **even if it "works", it might only supply to the
>   host the same packets that would be seen in non-promiscuous mode**.
>   Although it can receive, at the radio level, packets on other SSID's,
>   it will not forward them to the host.

[Monitor Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode) (which I believe is what you want) will capture all traffic from the SSID, and other SSIDs in range.

The Wireshark documentation continues:

> Therefore, in order to capture all traffic that the adapter can
>   receive, the adapter must be put into "monitor mode", sometimes called
>   "rfmon mode". In this mode, the driver will put the adapter in a mode
>   where it will supply to the host packets from all service sets.
>   Depending on the adapter and the driver, this might disassociate the
>   adapter from the SSID, so that the machine will not be able to use
>   that adapter for network traffic, or it might leave the adapter
>   associated, so that it can still be used for network traffic. If it
>   disassociates the adapter from the SSID, and the host doesn't have any
>   other network adapters, it will not be able to:
>
> ```
> * resolve addresses to host names using a network protocol such as DNS;
> * save packets to a file on a network file server;
> * etc..
> ```
>
> Monitor mode is not supported by WinPcap, and thus not by Wireshark or
>   TShark, on Windows. It is supported, for at least some interfaces, on
>   some versions of Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, DragonFly BSD, and
>   Mac OS X.
>
> You might have to perform operating-system-dependent and
>   adapter-type-dependent operations to enable monitor mode, described
>   below in the "Turning on monitor mode" section.

Source: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#A802.11_Filter_.28Modes.29

Comment: thanks bro, that was clear. I guess that my AP is applying client isolation, that's why the promiscuous mode isn't giving me any extra packets than the normal mode. I tried the monitor mode in wireshark, but isn't working well neither. Well, at least i'm going forward, and i understand now why the promiscuous mode isn't working. Thanks bro.